# Main method invocation in scala nsc

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, program-entry-point, scalac, scala-compiler

I was trying to go through the code for nsc(new scala compiler). I am a little confused about [`Main.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/Main.scala). It is implemented as follows:

```
/* NSC -- new Scala compiler
 * Copyright 2005-2013 LAMP/EPFL
 * @author  Martin Odersky
 */
package scala.tools
package nsc

import scala.language.postfixOps

/** The main class for NSC, a compiler for the programming
 *  language Scala.
 */
class MainClass extends Driver with EvalLoop {
  def resident(compiler: Global): Unit = loop { line =>
    val command = new CompilerCommand(line split "\\s+" toList, new Settings(scalacError))
    compiler.reporter.reset()
    new compiler.Run() compile command.files
  }

  override def newCompiler(): Global = Global(settings, reporter)
  override def doCompile(compiler: Global) {
    if (settings.resident) resident(compiler)
    else super.doCompile(compiler)
  }
}

object Main extends MainClass { }
```

My first question is, how is `Main` being called by the compiler process? When I call something along the lines of:

```
scalac [ <options> ] <source files>
```

Somewhere along the lines the `newCompiler` and `doCompile` is being called, can somebody help me with tracing through how this is being called and how the compiler is being initialized?

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainClass` extends `Driver` which has the `main` method:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  process(args)
  sys.exit(if (reporter.hasErrors) 1 else 0)
}
```

At the same time, object `Main` extends `MainClass` which means that there is a `Main.class` file that contains a `public static void main(String[] args)` forwarder method that actually invokes aforementioned non-static method on object `Main`. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783994/why-is-a-scala-companion-object-compiled-into-two-classesboth-java-and-net-com) for more details on how `object` is compiled in Scala.

This means that `scala.tools.nsc.Main` can be used as a *main class* when running the scala compiler (this is hardcoded somewhere in the `scalac` script).

`newCompiler` and `doCompile` are called by `process`.