# Reflect Scala object from Java

Tags: java, scala

Is it possible to get a reference to a Scala Object class from Java, using reflection?

To illustrate what I mean, this is the Scala code for doing this (assume MyClass is a Scala Object):

```
  val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val module = runtimeMirror.staticModule("MyClass")
  val obj = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(module)
  val realObject: MyInterface = obj.instance.asInstanceOf[MyInterface]
```

In Java, I successfully loaded the Class, but I can't seem to be able to get an actual reference to the object; calling newInstance() on the class obviously fails since it doesn't have a public constructor.

I've managed to workaround it by getting its constructor by reflection and setting it to be accessible, but that seems like a hack to me.. is there a BKM for doing this sort of thing?

Comment: lots of reflection code does that... `setAcessible(true)` that is. You are already using *reflection*, which is already sort of a hack

Comment: Scala's object compiles to 2 `.class` files, one containing only the static forwarder to the implementation (singleton), called `$MODULE` and other one, inner class with `$` appended. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12785219/4496364. I guess you want the `MODULE$` instance...

Comment: @Eugene However, this particular use of `setAccessible` will give wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from insan-e mentioning MODULE$ did the trick.

The code below now works as expected (loading the class from an external jar file):

```
String className = "MyClass";
File f = new File("C:\\TEMP\\source.jar");
URLClassLoader urlCl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURI().toURL()}, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class c = urlCl.loadClass(className);
Field module = c.getField("MODULE$");
if (module.get(this) instanceof MyInterface) 
{
   MyInterface obj = (MyInterface) module.get(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answers to this question about the Java-equivalent implementation of Scala objects to understand how Scala objects translate to Java concepts

[What is the Java equivalent of a Scala object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819866/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-a-scala-object)